# LinkedList - Use Iterator for "get()" to iterate faster

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, iterator

I am reading this book: `Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in Java by Mark Weiss`. Could somebody please explain how using an iterator decreases the running time while calling the `get(i)` ?

The text snippet from the book:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Before we answer this: do you understand why `get(i)` is O(1) for an ArrayList, but O(n) for a LinkedList?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArrayList vs LinkedList for both Random-Access & Additions-Removals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986374/arraylist-vs-linkedlist-for-both-random-access-additions-removals)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    Integer[] elements = new Integer[] { 4, 2, 7, 8, 1, 0, 3, 5, 9, 6 };

    List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(elements));
    List<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(elements));

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { // Runs for O(n)
        Integer l1 = arrayList.get(i); // returns in O(1) 
        Integer l2 = linkedList.get(i); // returns in O(n)
    }
```

`get(index)` for *ArrayList* fetches the element at `index` directly from the memory location. 
Therefore, `get(index)` is in `O(1)`

`get(index)` for *LinkedList* fetches the element at `index` by traversing the list from head location of the LinkedList. There are no specified memory location which can be predicted for a given index element of LinkedList. 
Therefore, `get(index)` is in `O(n)`

Total running time for ArrayList = `O(1) * O(n)` = `O(n)`
Total running time for LinkedList = `O(n) * O(n)` = `O(n^2)`

---

Using **java.util.Iterator class**

```
    Iterator iterator = arrayList.iterator();

    // total execution time: O(N)
    while (iterator.hasNext()) { // runs for each element iteratively
        System.out.print(iterator.next());
    }
    System.out.println();

    iterator = linkedList.iterator();

    // total execution time: O(N)
    while (iterator.hasNext()) { // runs for each element iteratively
        System.out.print(iterator.next());
    }
    System.out.println();
```

The `iterator.next()` simply iterates to the next element in the `List`. The advantage of this is that we need not search for the `List Node` from the head of the list. `Iterator class` helps you to preserve address to the current `node` location os the `List`.

The same can be implemented using **for-each as iterator** which has a simpler code implementation.

```
    for (Integer I : arrayList) { // runs for each element: total execution time: O(N)
        System.out.print(I); // gets in O(1)
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (Integer I : linkedList) { // runs for each element: total execution time: O(N)
        System.out.print(I); // gets in O(1)
    }
```

Therefore using iterator, 
Total running time for ArrayList = `O(n)`
Total running time for LinkedList = `O(n)`

Comment: I wanted to know ... if I declare an iterator like , ListIterator k = myList.listIterator(0); and another 'ListIterator l = myList1.listIterator(0);' and try to do 'k.intValue() + l.intValue()' .... its shows error ..... it even shows no implementations for 'k.intValue()' possible ..... why is this happenning and how it is different from the 'for(Integer I : myList)' .

Answer (score 3):

This is because `get(i)` will start at the head node of a linked list and move to the next node successively until it returns a reference to the `i`th node, which is `O(n)` because it will have to go through `n`, or rather `i` different nodes before it returns a reference back to the caller. An iterator on the other hand, will store a current node, and each successive call to `next()` will simply advance the reference to point to the next node directly after the current node, which is an `O(1)` operation.

`get(i)` is generic and doesn't assume that you're iterating through the list, which means it doesn't know which node you were looking at previously (if at all). For this reason, it has to re-access the `i`th node by going through the head of the list once more. Using an iterator assumes iteration, which means the node you were looking at previously, or said another way, the node you will be looking at next, is assumed to be the *next* node, so the iterator can optimize by storing a reference to the *current* node. That way, it doesn't have to go through the head of the linked list to find the next node.